# How to get customers orders list using their own rest api creds

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a new Rest API credentials for a customer.

Now I am using the following api to get the orders for that particular user.

```
/wp-json/wc/v3/orders
```

but I get the following error in the response

```
{
    "code": "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view",
    "message": "Sorry, you cannot list resources.",
    "data": {
        "status": 403
    }
}
```

I have tried with both basic auth and keys in url parameter, but it's not working. If the rest api belongs to that particular user then it should return the users order but it is giving me error.

Please help

Even I am not able to get the product list with the customer's api credentials.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. The REST API doesn't belong to a customer, it's just WooCommerce functionality.
2. You need to create API keys for yourself - the user that will be using the REST API.  Not for the customer whose information you need.  If THAT customer will be using your site's REST API, he will need his own credentials.
3. The endpoint you're using will give you all orders.  For a specific one, you need to use this endpoint:  `/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/<id>` (replace "<id>" by an order ID).
4. For orders of a specific customer, you can add a customer parameter ([List all orders documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-orders)

In the Postman Authorization tab, choose "Basic Auth", enter the key and secret there, and test it with the "All orders" endpoint.  That should work.

Comment: thanks for the reply but like I am create a app based on woocomerce api. now a customer logged in into app. then he want to see his orders  then I cant able to fetch the details with his own api credentials why?  I am generating rhe api creds at the time of registration of the customer.

Comment: In this case you can make a WordPress user for your app and generate API credentials for that user.  That is how I did it so our interal ERP can use the WooCommerce API.

Comment: yes I am doing this  but I am not able to fetch the users data. by his own api creds

Comment: thats why I have provided the SS where you can see that I have generated  the api creds for specific user and tried to access his orders

Comment: What I mean is, you DON'T create API creds for each user.  You create it only once, for your application (you can create a WP user for this application, or use your WP user).  Whenever you application calls the API, it uses IT'S credentials.  Your users do NOT need API credentials.